# @Caching method called from spring boot test [annotated with @Transactional] not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I'm using redis caching and spring boot annotations[@Cacheable and @CahePut], 
I made RedisManager transactionAware, which will use the outer transaction[callee of caching layer]

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager rcm = 
    RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory())
            .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration())
            .transactionAware()
            .build();
    return rcm;
}
```

while testing as below, I'm using embedded redis-:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@Transactional
public class RoleServiceImplTest extends TestingProfile {

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    //setup server and services

    redisServer = new RedisServer(redisPort);
    redisServer.start();
}
@Test
    public void getUsersForRoleForTemplateRole() {
    // call to caching layer methods directly annotated with @Cachable
}
```

...
Both times [ with and without @Transactional ] spring calls `cache.put(key,result)` without exception but it only persists values in case of without @Transactional.

Couldn't find much on internet, kudos to any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In short just put `@Commit` or `Rollback(false)` annotation over your class or test method.

Spring by default rollback every Transaction after the test method.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx

> In the TestContext framework, transactions are managed by the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`, which is configured by default, even if you do not explicitly declare `@TestExecutionListeners` on your test class. To enable support for transactions, however, you must configure a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean in the `ApplicationContext` that is loaded with `@ContextConfiguration` semantics (further details are provided later). In addition, you must declare Spring’s `@Transactional` annotation either at the class or the method level for your tests.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html

> ***Declarative Rollback and Commit Behavior***
>
> By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after completion of the test; however, transactional commit and rollback behavior can be configured declaratively via the `@Commit` and `@Rollback` annotations at the class level and at the method level.

Comment: I tried a separate transaction to commit the cache changes, and that works!!

Comment: Can you post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)